# A basic combinatorics/probability question

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Suppose you have a set $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$.

You do a sampling with replacement over A (uniformly at random), and get a multiset/bag $B$ of size $5$. For instance, B could be $\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ or $\{2, 2, 3, 3, 4\}$.

Then what is the probability that there are at least $3$ distinct elements in $B$?

More generally, if you have $A = \{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$, you do a sampling with replacement over $A$ and get a multiset/bag $B$ of size $k$, what is the probability that there are at least m distinct elements in B? (assuming $n > k > m$).

Comment: For the specific question, it shouldn't be hard to calculate the probability of exactly one element in $B$, or of exactly two distinct elements in $B$; from those numbers, you can get the probability of at least 3 distinct elements in $B$.

Comment: This is essentially a "balls and bins" problem - we take $k$ balls and toss them independently and uniformly into $n$ bins, and you are asking for the probability that at least $m$ bins contain a ball.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to do the calculation that there are exactly $m$ bins with at least one ball.  $k$ does not need to be less than $n$.

You have a recurrence with $P(n,k,m)=\frac{n-m+1}{n}P(n,k-1,m-1)+\frac{m}{n}P(n,k-1,m)$ starting at $P(n,0,0)=1$.

So for your example with $n=7$ you get something like this, with each column summing to $1$.

```
n=7     k:  0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
m:                                      
0       1.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
1       0.000   1.000   0.143   0.020   0.003   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000
2       0.000   0.000   0.857   0.367   0.122   0.037   0.011   0.003   0.001
3       0.000   0.000   0.000   0.612   0.525   0.312   0.161   0.077   0.035
4       0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.350   0.500   0.464   0.357   0.248
5       0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.150   0.321   0.428   0.459
6       0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.043   0.129   0.233
7       0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.006   0.024
```

So for $k=5$ you just sum the suitable figures in the relevant column to give an answer of about $0.962099\ldots$